# sequence of execution in Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I'm a bit new to chef. I'm just wondering if chef resources are like node-js.

For example,

***`recipe.rb`***

```
resource1 'foo' do
    property value
end

resource2 'bar' do
    property value
end
```

Consider that `resource1` is a heavy weight process and `resource2` is a light weight process. Is it possible that `bar` will be executed first and then `foo` in this case? Or will it be in sequence manner first `foo` will be executed and then `bar`.

Comment: "like node-js" isn't a very useful description. After all, Node may have an async model, but still has imperative commands executed in order.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chef recipes are imperative, they will run in a sequence. The run list is also an array which will be run in order. Unless you define the same thing in the run list multiple times, then only the first will run.

There are two stages to a chef run though. A compile phase, to organise what resources need to be run and resolve all variables. Then a run phase where each resource is actually executed. You can write recipes that trigger actions during the compile phase which may make it seem out of order.

For example, the [`chef_gem`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_chef_gem.html) resource is designed to do things at the compile stage so the gems are available during the run phase. The `compile_time` option can be used to turn this off.

For a functional example...

```
ruby_block "later" do
  block do
    Chef::Log.info "I am first in the file"
  end
end

Chef::Log.info "I am second in the file"
```

The ruby block is a resource that is compiled for later execution.
The ruby code is executed during compilation, so comes out first.

Comment: Just a little precision, if a recipe is declared more than once in the run list, it will keep the first position only and will not be included again in the runlist.

Comment: Also, it's possible for Ruby code to re-order the resources at any point during compilation, so it might be worth mentioning that the re-ordering could change things before convergence of the resources in the resource collection.